# How to convert filetype using GraphicsMagick for node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick, format-conversion

How do you "Convert" a file from one type to another using gm? (e.g .png > .jpg)

I found [this](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html) but it doesn't seem that [the node.js version](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#manipulation) has the same method:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to change the format of the output file.

```
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("output.jpg");
gm("img.png").setFormat("jpg").write(writeStream, function(error){
    console.log("Finished saving", error);
});
```

http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#setformat

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for sharing. What was interesting is the file extension I was writting will still PNG, so I had to specifically set the output as JPG and trust this code to work. And it does :) https://YouDoer.com to see it working :)